# Are there any good, general optimization algorithms for nonlinear regression in R?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-regression

I have generated data similar to a model I want to build:

```
n = 1000

sample_data = data.frame(
  t = pmax(3, 4+rnorm(n)*3),
  x1 = rnorm(n),
  x2=rbinom(n, 50, 0.5)
) 

B1 = 100
B2 = 0.5
B3 = 5
B4 = 0.1
B5 = 0.1
B6 = 0.01

sample_data$y = with(sample_data, x1 + 
 (B1-x1+B2*x2) * (exp(max(t-(B3+B4*x2), 0) * (B5 + B6*x2)))) + rnorm(n)*50
```

This is similar to a thermodynamic system where a second unknown "temperature" exists `(B1+B2*x2)`, along with a lag in a changing effect `(B3+B4*x2)`, as well as a coefficient for that rate `(B5+B6*x2)`.

My main goal in this scenario is to extract the parameters so that I can describe the underlying phenomena of the model.

I have attempted to use `nls()`, but it seems to be having difficulties with the specific model I am using, as I do not want to assume any coefficients for certain variables, including `x1` and `t`, as the former is theoretically restricted, and the latter would be redundant.

I have attempted to build a log-likelihood function that takes in these parameters, as well as a $\hat{\sigma}^2$ estimate for the error, and then use `optim()` to maximize the log likelihood:

```
make_ll_function <- function(
  data
){

  # function to return
  model_func <- function(X){
    B1 = X[1]
    B2 = X[2]
    B3 = X[3]
    B4 = X[4]
    B5 = X[5]
    B6 = X[6]
    sigma2 = X[7]

    estimates = with(
      data,
      x1 + (B1-x1+B2*x2) * (exp(pmax(t-(B3+B4*x2), 0) * (B5 + B6*x2)))
    ) 

    ll = -nrow(data)/2 * log(sigma2)  - 
      1/sigma2*sum(
        (data$y - estimates)^2
      )
    # invert for maximization
    return(-ll)
  }
  return(model_func)
}

initial_values = c(
  50,#B1
  1, #B2
  1, #B3
  1, #B4
  1, #B5
  0.1, #B6
  1000 # ballpark estimate of sigma^2
)

model_func = make_ll_function(sample_data)

(model_params = optim(initial_values, model_func,
                      method='SANN',
                      control=list(
                        maxit=100000,
                        ndeps=1e-4,
                        tmax=100,
                        temp=5
                      )))
```

When I run this, though, the parameter estimates are nothing like the original values. This is true even if I reduce the amount of error on the `y` term to have a standard deviation of 1.

The results are similar or worse for different optimization algorithms, and it is representative of the issue I am having with the regular data.

As for additional solutions I've tried:

1. Increasing sample size barely helps
2. Adding a huge penalty for any parameter going out of bounds (`< 0` in this case) seems to work surprisingly well (I got an R^2 of about 0.8). I am guessing the behavior of the functions changes dramatically enough when certain signs are flipped that should not be flipped.

In many cases, though, I cannot rely heavily on (2), as I do not have a good idea of the bounds of a variable. I can possibly constrain the calculated quantities (e.g., `B3+B4*x2`) themselves to something reasonable using the same penalty method, but that's about it.

Edit: fixed `max()`->`pmax()`

Comment: my guess would be that there are identifiability issues, meaning that no choice of optimization routine will solve the issue. If two parameters are multiplying one another, they are not identifiable. This can sometimes be obscured by exponentiation (since exp(a + b) = exp(a)exp(b)).

Comment: I can see a similar effect with the above due to likely correlated parameters (though I haven't calculated any covariances), although the first term of the exponential is not 100% separable due to the `max()` function (it depends on the data, though), and the second term is multiplying another, which is identical to it being an exponent (like `(e^max(...))^(B5+B6*x2)`. I'm not sure how to deal with this, though.